# What is this line in the shell script doing?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

Could some explain to me what this line of code is doing in a shell script i am looking at?

```
typeset -i NOTIFY=0
```

I understand that typeset is used for declaring/displaying variables with attributes. I am assuming that here a variable called NOTIFY that is an integer value is being declared and the value of the NOTIFY variable is initialized to zero.

This may be wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your assessment is correct that `NOTIFY` is an integer initialized to 0

Answer (score 4):

`typeset` is a deprecated* builtin command that is the same as `declare`.

```
$ help typeset
typeset: typeset [-afFirtx] [-p] name[=value] ...
    Obsolete.  See `declare'.
```

So this:

```
typeset -i NOTIFY=0
```

does the same thing as this:

```
declare -i NOTIFY=0
```

namely, to declare `NOTIFY` as an integer and set its value to `0`.

*(The `help` text writer and I disagree on what *obsolete* means. Since it still seems to *exist*, but its use is discouraged, I say it's *deprecated*, not *obsolete*. YMMV)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @kojiro's answer, declaring a variable to be integer only means it can only hold integers. Also it appears to force variable assignments to be performed in arithmetic context where `$` sigils are optional:

```
$ declare -i foo
$ unset bar
$ foo=bar         # no error assigning a string to foo
$ echo $foo
0
$ bar=5
$ foo=bar
$ echo $foo
5
$ foo++
bash: foo++: command not found
$ foo+=1
$ echo $foo
6
```

Also, demonstrating bash's interger-only arithmetic:

```
$ bar=3.14
$ foo=bar
bash: 3.14: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".14")
```

Comment: This can get pretty nuanced, by the way. For example, `declare -i foo bar; baz=bar; bar=3; foo=baz; echo $foo` -> 3